# get jQuery sort order after moving sortable divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created what could be described as a horizontal kanban board using jQuery's sortable feature.  I now need to send the new sort order to the backend and I'm having a hard time figuring out how exactly to capture the new sort order to do so.

In the HTML tag the "id" is the pk for the object and the "data-sort" is the current sort order.

I suspect I need two different functions.  One to POST when the row order changes, and the second to POST when an item in the row changes.

This snippet gives me the id and new sort location of the item I moved, but I can't figure out how to get for all the div's in the parent (or it's siblings).

```
$(function() {
    $(".swim-lane-wrapper").sortable({
        axis: "Y",
        handle: ".category-card",
        connectWith: ".swim-lane-wrapper",

        update: function(event, ui) {
            console.log(ui.item.context.children["0"].id)
            console.log(ui.item.index())
        },
    });
});
```

Here's the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f8f9q33b/2/)

And a snippet:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".swim-lane-wrapper").sortable({
    axis: "Y",
    handle: ".category-card",
    connectWith: ".swim-lane-wrapper",

    update: function(event, ui) {
      console.log(ui)
    },
  })
});

$(function() {
  $(".item-row-wrapper")
    .sortable({
      connectWith: ".item-row-wrapper",
      update: function(event, ui) {},
    })
    .disableSelection();
});
```

```css
.swim-lane-wrapper {}

.swim-lane {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.category-card {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  float: left;
  background-color: #FFF3CC;
  border: #DFBC6A 1px solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 85px;
  line-height: 85px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #999;
  cursor: move;
}

.category-text {
  padding: 0px 8px 0px 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  white-space: normal;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 80%
}

.item-card {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #edf3ff;
  border: #6d71db 1px solid;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 85px;
  line-height: 85px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #999;
  cursor: move;
}

.item-text {
  padding: 0px 8px 0px 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  white-space: normal;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 80%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<div class="swim-lane-wrapper">

  <div class="swim-lane">
    <!-- Category -->
    <div class="category-card" id="1" data-sort="1">
      <div class="category-text">
        <span>Category 1</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Items -->
    <div class="item-row-wrapper">
      <div class="item-card">
        <div class="item-text">
          <span class="sort-item">Item 11</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item-card">
        <div class="item-text">
          <span class="sort-item">Item 12</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item-card">
        <div class="item-text">
          <span class="sort-item">Item 13</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="swim-lane">
    <!-- Category -->
    <div class="category-card" id="2" data-sort="2">
      <div class="category-text">
        <span>Category 2</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Items -->
    <div class="item-row-wrapper">

      <div class="item-card">
        <div class="item-text">
          <span class="sort-item">Item 21</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item-card">
        <div class="item-text">
          <span class="sort-item">Item 22</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item-card">
        <div class="item-text">
          <span class="sort-item">Item 23</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Put ID's on items and on parent wrappers. When something gets moved store it's parent and sort order. Then when you build page you have a parent to put items in and order of those items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can access the parent and its children using this syntax in your `update` function:
(See comments in the JS code)

```js
$(function() {
  $(".swim-lane-wrapper").sortable({
    axis: "Y",
    handle: ".category-card",
    connectWith: ".swim-lane-wrapper",

    update: function(event, ui) {
      /* Modified here */
      var parent = ui.item.parent();
      $(parent).find('.category-card').each(function(i){
        console.log("ID of elm", i, ":", $(this).attr("id"));
      });
      
    },
  })
});

$(function() {
  $(".item-row-wrapper")
    .sortable({
      connectWith: ".item-row-wrapper",
      update: function(event, ui) {},
    })
    .disableSelection();
});
```

```css
.swim-lane-wrapper {}

.swim-lane {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.category-card {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  float: left;
  background-color: #FFF3CC;
  border: #DFBC6A 1px solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 85px;
  line-height: 85px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #999;
  cursor: move;
}

.category-text {
  padding: 0px 8px 0px 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  white-space: normal;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 80%
}

.item-card {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #edf3ff;
  border: #6d71db 1px solid;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 85px;
  line-height: 85px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #999;
  cursor: move;
}

.item-text {
  padding: 0px 8px 0px 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  white-space: normal;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 80%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<div class="swim-lane-wrapper">

  <div class="swim-lane">
    <!-- Category -->
    <div class="category-card" id="1" data-sort="1">
      <div class="category-text">
        <span>Category 1</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Items -->
    <div class="item-row-wrapper">
      <div class="item-card">
        <div class="item-text">
          <span class="sort-item">Item 11</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item-card">
        <div class="item-text">
          <span class="sort-item">Item 12</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item-card">
        <div class="item-text">
          <span class="sort-item">Item 13</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="swim-lane">
    <!-- Category -->
    <div class="category-card" id="2" data-sort="2">
      <div class="category-text">
        <span>Category 2</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Items -->
    <div class="item-row-wrapper">

      <div class="item-card">
        <div class="item-text">
          <span class="sort-item">Item 21</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item-card">
        <div class="item-text">
          <span class="sort-item">Item 22</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item-card">
        <div class="item-text">
          <span class="sort-item">Item 23</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

`.find()` looks for all the children that fulfill the required query.

Hope it's helpful!

Comment: I get what you're doing, but how do I then loop through the elements that match this: `<div class="category-card">`?

Comment: @pheeper I updated my answer. I hope that what's you want!

Comment: This is works, thanks.  I just needed to add a counter `i` so I could capture the sort order.  With the change the loop now looks like this: `$(parent).find('.category-card').each(function(i){ ... });`

Comment: @pheeper I'm glad it helped. :) I modified a little my code according to your comment. Cheers!